# WinOnX how to install DirectX

Tags: windows, games, wine

I want to play a cool game called Just Cause 2. I have a copy, but there is a problem because it needs DirectX 11. Anybody knows how I can install that DirectX? Because I think it's only for Windows, but I don't know WinOnX is emulating Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

WinOnX is a repackaging of the Wine framework. Wine does not emulate Windows (strictly speaking), it just provides adapter libraries to allow Windows programs to run. According to [this](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11316) page, Just Cause 2's compatibility with Wine is rated "garbage" and it doesn't run. There is also a link to [this](http://www.winehq.org/site/status/directx) page that shows the progress of re-creating the DirectX DLLs for Wine. As of early June 2012, they seem to be about 37% complete with DirectX versions 8-10, and there's no indication of work on DirectX 11 yet.

tl;dr: It won't work. You need to virtualize a real copy of Windows using VMware or Parallels or run Windows in Boot Camp to play a DirectX game like that on your Mac.